# Module data not copied when duplicating pages

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I get some DNN 9 modules developed. They are Slider and FAQ for example. 
When I try to duplicate a page, only these modules data is copied and I had to copy it again. Can you please tell me what elements need to be adjusted so data is copied as developer now telling me big stories that there is so much work involved in it?

thanks,
-Naveed

Answer (score 0):

When duplicating a DNN page, if you want the same module content to be "shared" between the two pages - You must add the modules as a "Reference":

[image: DNN Reference Modules]

This example above is for DNN9 - But the same logic applies for older versions, the interface is just slightly different.

If you now edit one of these modules on a duplicated page, the same changes will also be applied on the original page - As well as other "reference copies"

Comment: Hi Briksy89, 
Thank you very much for replying to me. my website is developed using DNN 9.2 but I do not see this New|Reference options. can you please tell me why? pls check screenshot here: https://snag.gy/PRmljf.jpg

Comment: I feel that in this screenshot - You are looking at the module settings for a page which already exists - Rather than a page which is about to exist. I can see at the top it says "Duplicate Page" - I believe if you click this it will have a similar layout to that in my screenshot. My version is also 9.2.0

Comment: @NaveedAhmed - If this answer helped you, please mark it as solved... If you are still stuck - Please let me know and I'll try to assist further.